# Can I view two buffers with a vertical split in emacs?

Tags: emacs

I know that ^-X 2 splits the screen horizontally between two buffers.

I'd like to split it vertically, though - how do I do this with emacs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`C-x 3` is the default binding for split-window-horizontally.

---

*Note:* my intuitive understanding of a "horizontal" split is what, in emacs-specific-lingo, is a "vertical" split, and vice-versa. (brought into answer from drew's comment below)

Comment: And by "horizontally" Emacs means what you (@blueberryfields) are asking for: splitting into two windows side by side.  What you call splitting horizontally (what `C-x 2` does) is what Emacs calls splitting vertically (into two windows one above the other).